# kubernetes: access Ingress within a Pod

Tags: kubernetes

I have an `Ingress` object set up to route traffic to the appropriate `Service` based on the `Url` path. I would like to access/expose this `Ingress` object within another `Pod`. I'm wondering if this is possible?

I tried to set up a `Service` on the `Ingress` but that didn't seem to work.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Are you trying to send http requests to the Pod behind the Ingress from another pod?

Comment: Exactly, I would like for a container on a Pod to be able to make (http) requests to an Ingress in the same cluster.

Comment: Why don't you send the requests to the `Service` object directly? `Ingress` is used usually for external traffic.

Answer (score 10):

So, for whatever reason (ssr, lots of microservices, etc) you want to access k8s resources using their ingress path mapping, instead of calling each service by its internal name.
For example, you have an ingress config like that:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-service
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: 'true'
spec:
  rules:
    - host: example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /api/users/?(.*)
            backend:
              serviceName: auth-service
              servicePort: 80
          - path: /api/cart/?(.*)
            backend:
              serviceName: cart-service
              servicePort: 80
```

and you want to access `auth-service` using `http://example.com/api/auth` instead of `http://auth-service`.

All you have to do is replace domain part (`example.com` in our case) with ingress service url. It depends on your configuration and environment, but usually it looks like `http://[SERVICE_NAME].[NAMESPACE]`, for example:

- GCP - `http://ingress-nginx-controller.ingress-nginx`
- Helm ingress nginx - `http://my-release-ingress-nginx-controller` (here we are
  using only service name part, because helm installs ingress in
  default namespace)
- Minikube - if you are using minikube ingress
  addon, then you might run into problem where you cannot access
  ingress, then just use helm version. (dont disable ingress addon - just install helm version alongside of it)

Get namespaces: `kubectl get namespaces`
Get service names inside namespace `kubectl get services -n [NAMESPACE]`.

Answer (score 2):

If you have assigned a host name, you also have to provide the domain name and IP address of the cluster to the /etc/hosts file. When you access a service via Ingress from outside the cluster, this is the file that is consulted for host name resolution.

However, a pod running inside a cluster does not have access to this /etc/hosts file. It has its own /etc/hosts file. To use ingress, the pod needs to have the same domain name and  IP address entry in it's own /etc/hosts file.

To achieve this, you have to use **hostAliases**. Here's a sample of how that works:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
...
spec:
  hostAliases:
  - ip:<IP address>
    hostnames:
    - <host name>
```

For more detail on hostAliases, go to [this link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/add-entries-to-pod-etc-hosts-with-host-aliases/)

Answer (score 0):

I have spend so much time on this issue. I found very simple solution. I am using `Mac Docker Desktop 3.3.1`.

My Kubernetes Version: `1.19.7`

I am trying to access UI URL from another pod running in the cluster.

###### My UI Service

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-ui-service
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: my-ui
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
```

###### Ingress for the service

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - host: my-site.com
    http:
      paths:
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: /
        backend:
          service:
            name: my-ui-service
            port:
              number: 8080
```

I have used `NGINX Ingress Controller`.

Command to run the Ingress Controller:

`kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/controller-v0.48.1/deploy/static/provider/cloud/deploy.yaml`

Once the controller is ready run the command to see the status of ingress.

`kubectl get ingress`

Now see the description of the ingress:

`kubectl describe ingress my-ingress`

Here you will find

```
Rules:
  Host           Path  Backends
  ----           ----  --------
  my-site.com
                 /   my-ui-service:8080 (10.1.2.198:8080)
```

In any pod in the cluster you can access the domain `my-site.com` by using `my-ui-service:8080`.

Comment: This is just calling the services that are targeting the deployments/pods. This is actually not using anything of ingress.

Answer (score -1):

**Inside** your cluster your pods use `services` to reach other pods.

**From outside** the cluster a client may use `ingress` to reach services.

Ingress resource allows connection to services.
So your pod need to be reachable by a service (my-svc-N in the following example), which you're going to use in your ingress definition.

Take a look at this example:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: example-ing
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  backend:
    serviceName: default-http-backend
    servicePort: 80
  rules:
  - host: my-kube.info
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: my-svc-1
          servicePort: 80
  - host: cheeses.all
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /aaa
        backend:
          serviceName: my-svc-2
          servicePort: 80
      - path: /bbb
        backend:
          serviceName: my-svc-3
          servicePort: 80
```

Comment: Ingresses only handle traffic from outside the cluster.